# Finding virtual screen width using multiple monitors and different DPI

Tags: c#, sendinput, virtual-screen

I'm trying to simulate mouse input using `SendInput`, however I need to determine the virtual screen width in case there are multiple monitors, to set the `dx` and `dy` values, for example:

```
dx = (x * 65536) / SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
dy = (y * 65536) / SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
```

The problem is that the monitors apparently have different DPI values, which results in an incorrect virtual size.
For reference, both `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size` and calls to `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)` return the same incorrect values.

I tried using `GetSystemMetricsForDPI` with no success either.

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62798145/126995

Comment: @Soonts no. You're talking about scalling the application. I'm trying to compute the virtual screen size as stated in the title.

Comment: These DPI virtualization shenanigans don’t just scale the application’s GUI, they affect many OS APIs, including both SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size and GetSystemMetrics. When the app declares it supports per-monitor DPI, Windows stops lying about screen sizes, these API will then return you true hardware pixels.

Comment: Wait, this actually does solve the problem, but why? The sample manifest states: `Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher DPIs.` It also states the WPF applications have this by default, but I'm actually doing this in a WPF app using `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth` and the results aren't right. I'll take a look at this again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Windows applies DPI virtualization to all coordinates.

If you have 2 displays, secondary FullHD on the left with 100% scaling, and primary 4k on the right with 200% DPI scaling, the APIs for screen configuration gonna tell you the desktop has 3840x1080 pixels, the secondary one from [-1920 .. 0], the primary one [0 .. 1920]. To simulate mouse input at the center of the left monitor, you should use X coordinate -960 * 0x10000 / 1920 = -32768 without `MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK` flag, or 960 * 0x10000 / 3840 = 16384 with `MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK` flag

You can tell Windows to stop messing with DPI in your application, [with a manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process).

If you do that on the same computer, the APIs for screen configuration gonna tell you the desktop has 5760x2160 pixels, the secondary one is the same, in [-1920 .. 0 ], the primary one [ 0 .. 3840 ]. To send mouse input to the center of the left monitor in this case, you should use X coordinate -960 * 0x10000 / 3840 = -16384 without `MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK` flag, or 960 * 0x10000 / 5760 = 10923 with `MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK` flag.